# How to write bytes individually into a file in C?

Tags: c, windows, file

I have an array of ints where every cell is a number between 0-255 representing a byte I want to write to the output file.
I have written this simple loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len ; i++)
    putc(write_buffer[i], OutputFile);
```

However after reviewing the output file using hex editor, I found that certain bytes have been duplicated and/or moved around within the file.

For example with the input array:

```
int write_buffer[10]= {137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0}
```

The output file contents (in decimal) are: 137 80 78 71 **13** 13 10 26 **13** 10 0 0

Does anyone have a clue as for what could be causing this?

Comment: 13 and 10 are windows new line chars, as opposed to 10 on unix like systems. it seems it proactively translates 10 aka \n to 13, 10 aka \r\n

Comment: We'd like to see your full source code. Please edit your question and post it. `putc` is a macro. `write_buffer[i]` has _no_ side effects so it should be okay. Have you tried the `fputc` function?

Comment: Based on Mirronelli's analysis, use `"wb" ` with your `fopen`

Answer (score 3):

Psychic debugging: You opened the file in text mode on Windows passing [`fopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-160) with mode `"wt"` or, when [`_fmode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/fmode?view=msvc-160) is set to `_O_TEXT`, which is the default, `"w"`, which means it's applying line ending translation, converting LF (`'\n'`/`10`) to CRLF (`'\r' '\n'`, `13 10`).

Change your `fopen` to pass a mode of `"wb"`, not just `"w"`/`"wt"`, so the file is operating in binary mode, and the translation won't be performed with any C stdio functions.

[pts made a useful note in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66787914/how-to-write-bytes-individually-into-a-file-in-c/66788050?noredirect=1#comment118061625_66788050): If you didn't open the file yourself (using `stdout`, or a handle opened by code you don't control), you can switch it to binary mode with `setmode(fileno(OutputFile), O_BINARY);` (for `stdout`, `1` can replace the first argument).

Comment: FYI To enable binary mode on stdout, call `setmode(1, O_BINARY);`. To enable binary mode on any filehandle (after it has been opened), call `setmode(fileno(OutputFile), O_BINARY);`.

Comment: @pts: Thanks for that addition; hadn't considered the OP (or a future reader) might be writing to `stdout` piped to a file, which would behave this way and not have the same solution. I'd *think* it would be less confusing there (`stdout` is usually used for text output, and you expect text translation there), but "confuses fewer people, but is even more confusing for the ones caught up" isn't much of an improvement. I added it to my answer just to make sure it's visible.